# How to use Google Cloud Functions with custom Google Cloud endpoints?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-functions

I want to use Google Cloud Functions in a similar way to Lambda Functions from Amazon's API Gateway.
Is this currently possible?

```
User → Google Cloud Endpoints → Google Cloud Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, I'm hoping they add this feature soon as it will clean up Cloud Functions.  Currently, the two best products to utilize with Cloud Endpoints is App Engine and Kubernetes Engine.

I will update this answer when they do, I'm constantly looking for the announcement, it might not happen until Google Next 2018 conference.

Comment: There is only one region for cloud functions. it is us-central1. do you know why it is?

Comment: Probably because it is in beta.  I'm sure they will role out other regions in the future.

Comment: The future is now the present, [Cloud Functions is no longer in beta](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/release-notes#april_1_2019), and there are multiple regions available: `curl -H"authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$(gcloud config get-value project)/locations`